# xterm's are being closed while debugging an MPI application

Tags: debugging, mpi, lldb, xterm

I have a problem debugging MPI application with `lldb`. Essentially, i attach it to every process via

```
mpirun_lldb() {
mpirun --mca orte_base_help_aggregate 0 --mca mpi_abort_print_stack 1 -np $1 xterm -hold -e lldb -f $2 -- "${@:3}"
}
```

but at some point `MPI_Abort` happens and all `xterm` windows are being closed immediately and I can't even read the stack, leave alone debugging and inspecting variables:

```
MPI_ABORT was invoked on rank 2 in communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
with errorcode 255.

NOTE: invoking MPI_ABORT causes Open MPI to kill all MPI processes.
You may or may not see output from other processes, depending on
exactly when Open MPI kills them.
```

I tried using `-hold` for `xterm` but this does not help.

p.s. I don't have access to licensed debuggers like TotalView. It's a first time i have a problem with a simple method described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for noise, adding a breakpoint `b MPI_Abort` solved the issue.

Comment: can you please write the full command you used?